# For loop not incrementing

Tags: c++, for-loop

Sorry but this is a quick question, can anyone tell why this for loop is not incrementing either i or j? They are staying at 0 and 1.

```
void Environment::tourneyselection(std::vector<Tree>& popvec) {
    std:random_shuffle(popvec.begin(), popvec.end());
    for (int i = 0, j = 1; j <= Popsize; i + 2, j + 2) {
        std::cout << popvec[i].fitness << " and " << popvec[j].fitness << ":";
        if (popvec[i].fitness < popvec[j].fitness) {
            popvec.erase(popvec.begin() + i);
            std::cout << " erase " << i << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            popvec.erase(popvec.begin() + j);
            std::cout << " erase " << j << std::endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `j+2` doesn't do anything useful. Try `j+=2`.

Comment: `i + 2, j + 2` are NOPs actually. use `i += 2, j += 2)` instead.

Comment: That seems to produce errors. ; i += 2, j += 2)

Edit: Oh sorry no my debugger had just frozen up

Comment: @MushinZero Which ones specifically?

Comment: Nvm, that worked. Now I am getting vector out of range but I see that's because it eventually becomes smaller than iterator range. I am going to see if I cannot make the values empty and then resize the vector after.

Comment: @MushinZero Please stop asking that kind of questions at Stack Overflow. There's no value for future research, and we're not your personal help desk. Get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) about c++ and learn from there in 1st place.

Comment: Isn't asking questions the point? I have a couple books on C++ but I had just overlooked this. People forget things all the time.

Comment: @MushinZero Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) please. Then think twice before posting again.

Comment: The first link is an explanation to not post subjective questions, which this is not. The second is how to write a good question. While this is a simple question, it does not appear to break the rules that would categorize it as a bad question. Yes a little more searching would have probably helped, but I did google the question first and because it was overlooking a simple issue the highest answers were for deeper more complex problems with for loops than something simple like this and did not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
j + 2
```

You're not modifying `j` at all. You wanted to say

```
j += 2
```

The same thing goes for `i + 2`.

Comment: Yep, I feel dumb. Also hi, you have answered my question before!

Answer (score 1):

Neither `i + 2` nor `j + 2` are making an assignment, you're performing calculations but not assigning the result to either of `i` or `j`

Try `i += 2` and `j += 2`

Alternatively, if you want to keep it simple or just break it down a bit - try `i = (i + 2)` and `j = (j + 2)`

the `+=` operator allows you to perform the calculation while at the same time, assign the result.

Comment: Note the brackets are unnecessary due to operator precedence.